# How to use free on a handle inside a list?-> C -> windows API

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, handle, memory-corruption

I have a list in C that is something like this:

```
typedef struct _node
{
   int number;
   DWORD threadID;
   HANDLE threadH;
   struct *_node next;
} *node;
```

And you have somthing like this:

```
node new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

As you may have guessed out, this list will store information for threads, including their handlers and Id's. Still I am having trouble when I try to do this:

```
free(new_node);
```

Everytime I try to do this I encounter an unexpected error, VS saying that there was a data corruption. I've pinned down as much as possible and I found that the problem resides when I try to use free the handle.
I've searched on MSDN how to do this but the only thing I can find is the function that closes the thread (which is not intended here, since I want the thread to run, just deleting it's record from the list).

The question is: how I am supposed to free an handle from the memory? (Considering that this is only a copy of the value of the handle, the active handle is not being deleted).

EDIT: This is the function to insert nodes from the list:

```
int insereVisitanteLista(node* lista, DWORD threadID, HANDLE threadH, int num_visitante)
{
    node visitanteAnterior;
    node novoVisitante = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(novoVisitante == NULL)
        return 0;

    novoVisitante->threadID = threadID;
    novoVisitante->threadH = threadH;
    novoVisitante->number = num_visitante;
    novoVisitante->next = NULL;

    if(*lista == NULL)
    {
        *lista = novoVisitante;
        return 1;
    }

    visitanteAnterior = *lista;

    while(visitanteAnterior->next != NULL)
        visitanteAnterior = visitanteAnterior->next;

    visitanteAnterior->next =novoVisitante;
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the function to delete nodes:

```
int removeVisitanteLista(node * lista, DWORD threadID)
{
    node visitanteAnterior = NULL, visitanteActual;

    if(*lista == NULL)
        return 0;

    visitanteActual = *lista;

    if((*lista)->threadID == threadID)
    {
        *lista = visitanteActual->next;
        visitanteActual->next = NULL;
        free(visitanteActual);

        return 1;
    }

    while(visitanteActual != NULL && visitanteActual->threadID != threadID)
    {
        visitanteAnterior = visitanteActual;
        visitanteActual = visitanteActual->next;
    }

    if (visitanteActual == NULL)
        return 0;

    visitanteAnterior->next = visitanteActual->next;
    free(visitanteActual);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The list insertion/removal code looks good to me...

Comment: I think the same too.... dunno why the handle is giving me such a fight. Tried to cast the pointer of the handle to void*, no dice, setting the handle 1st to null, also no dice.... I am really not getting this one... And insertion always goes fine, removal never does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is a `node` that you are trying to free? Is this a pointer to a struct `_node`? If yes, have you allocated it previously? If no, `free` is not needed, otherwise you have to check if node is not `NULL` and make sure you do not `free` it multiple times. It is hard to guess what you are doing and where is an error without a minimal working example reproducing the problem. The only thing I can suggest is to read about memory management in C. [This resource](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Memory_management) might help.

UPDATE:

node in your code is a pointer to _node. So sizeof (node) is a size of a pointer, which is either 4 or 8 bytes (depending on architecture). So you allocate 8 bytes, for example, but assume you have a pointer to the structure which is much larger. As a result, you corrupt memory, and behavior of the program becomes undefined. So changing node novoVisitante = (node)malloc(sizeof(node)) to node novoVisitante = (node)malloc(sizeof(_node)) should fix the problem.

Comment: Well you're right I posted the question a little in a rush. Yes, the node is a *_node that is malloc'ed before without problem (and it is being accessed with the correct values I also checked that). I only try to free once (to delete a node from a list) and get the eror there. Suppose that you have something like _node * node = malloc(sizeof(node)); -> something in those lines

Comment: It is just impossible to get this error with `free (malloc (sizeof (_node)));` unless `malloc` returns NULL. So something else is going on there, that you are not telling :-)

Comment: Dunno what is.... BTW found another piece of info that might help: I checked the error given by VS and it seems that the error is reported right in the end of the void __cdecl _unlock function in the mlock.c file (I believe this is related to mutexes, semaphores and such). There is a problem to delete a handle when I am inside an exclusion area ? (Still doesn't make sense, since I am not deleting the handle itself). PS: I don't post the entire code cause is damn huge, if it wasn't for that I would post it right away EDIT: Added the function that add and delete nodes from the list

Comment: PS: There might be some syntax errors cause of the code translation, dont mind that,

Comment: @John: I've tracked down at least one major error that for sure crashes the whole thing. Fix it and let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: OMFG how can I be such a stupid dork? ..... Many thanks for the answer! Idd that was the catch here (and it does make sense, it wasn't saving a handle or any other object but a pointer to them) PS: Still scratching my head of how I did this mistake... did many other lists in the past...

Comment: Glad it worked out. Having `_node` and `node` where `node` is a `*_node` is very confusing :-) Next time you better pick something like `node` for struct and `node_ptr` for pointer. Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: Seems that is a better notation than mine (was just trying to avoid getting double pointers around the code). Merry Christmas to you too!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the context of your call to free() so I need to speculate a little but my first concern is that you didn't mention removing the node from the list before deleting it.

Start by unlinking the node by modifying the next field of the previous (or head) node. If you still get the error, then you have corrupted memory somehow by writing past the end of one of your allocated memory structures or something similar.

Also, I assume node is a pointer. You really haven't provided much information about what you're doing.

Comment: Well you're right I posted the question a little in a rush. Yes, the node is a *_node that is malloc'ed before without problem (and it is being accessed with the correct values I also checked that). I only try to free once (to delete a node from a list) and get the eror there.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to update my answer and edited yours :-))) I gotta get some sleep...

Comment: Vlad: I was trying to figure out what happened there. :-)